# append multiple rows to specific columns in empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have empty dataframe df1 of shape (0,227) and another dataframe df2 of shape (2,7). The result dataframe should have all the rows from df2 in df1 where all the columns between the 2 match. Following is my code

```
for i in df2.columns.tolist():
      for j in df1.columns.tolist():
            if(fuzz.token_sort_ratio(i,j)>85):
                 for t in range(len(df2)):
                      df1 = df1.append({j:df2.loc[:,i][t]},ignore_index=True)
```

I have applied fuzzy logic as the column names are not exactly similar. But the following code appends columns one by one instead of multiple columns at once hence introducing lot of NaN values. It gives output of the form

```
Moisture      Sodium 
15.74           NaN
12.36           NaN
NaN             0.57
NaN             0.57
```

Whereas the output should be something like this

```
  Moisture         Sodium 
    15.74           0.57
    12.36           0.57
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

df3 will produce the concatenated dataframe.

Comment: I could use that but the column names are not similar so instead of appending the contents of  'moisture (%)' to 'moisture', it will create a new column 'moisture (%)'